# Long exact sequence to short exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

$$\dots\xrightarrow{p_*}\pi_{n+1}(B)\xrightarrow{\partial}\pi_n(F)\xrightarrow{\text{inc}_*}\pi_n(E)\xrightarrow{p_*}\pi_n(B)\xrightarrow{\partial}\pi_{n-1}(F)\xrightarrow{\text{inc}_*}\dots$$
From the above how can one deduce a short exact sequence
$$0\to coker[\pi_{n+1}(B)\xrightarrow{\partial}\pi_n(F)]\xrightarrow{i}\pi_n(E)\xrightarrow{j}\ker[\pi_n(B)\xrightarrow{\partial}\pi_{n-1}(F)]\to 0$$

Do we need to use the snake lemma?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's a general fact about long exact sequence, there's nothing special about this particular one. You should try proving it yourself before reading the solution, it's a very instructive game of playing with the definitions.

Comment: No snake lemma needed.

Comment: Do $i$ and $j$ represent the inclusions? Also It seems that there is a "jump" in the short exact sequence, I thought it should be of the form $0\to \text{coker}\to \pi_n(E)\to\text{Image}$ rather than $0\to \text{coker}\to \pi_n(E)\to\text{Ker}$